# Running emacsclient with a script

Tags: shell-script, xorg, emacs

I'm trying to make a script to determine whether `emacsclient` should run with `-nc` or `-t`. The script is like this (based on [this version](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Emacs#As_a_daemon)):

```
#!/bin/sh 
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]; then 
    IS_GRAPHICAL=true 
else 
    IS_GRAPHICAL=$(emacs --batch -Q --eval='(if (fboundp '"'"'tool-bar-mode) (message "true") (message "false"))' 2>&1) 
fi 
if $IS_GRAPHICAL; then 
    emacsclient -a "" -nc "$@" 
else 
    emacsclient -a "" -t "$@" 
fi
```

However the `emacs --batch -Q ...` line takes as much time as using a bare `emacs` instance. If I comment out this line, I get nothing instead of a clean screen when this is executed under a tty. Is it possible to make the detection faster?

I have already started an emacs daemon using a systemd user unit. I want `emacsclient` to:

- stay **in the terminal** (that is, do not open a GUI window) if called with a file (e.g. called by `git-commit`) or when a graphical environment isn't present (e.g. called while in tty) and continue running until exit (`C-x C-c`)
- open a GUI window when called without a file (behave like bare `emacs` call; when I do this with `emacsclient` it tells me that input file is required) and return immediately.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. What is this test for `tool-bar-mode` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @Gilles Uh.. The script is mainly from [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Emacs#As_a_daemon) and I don't know either.

Comment: `emacs` is pretty good at understanding its environment, I'm guessing it's only the " in terminal while launched in terminal" part that's needs to be forced, yes?

Comment: @bsd Perhaps yes. When I use emc as $EDITOR git exits when trying to record commit message (aborting due to empty commit message)

Comment: Are you using Emerge? If so, there is a paragraph in the Emacs section of the Arch Wiki "Using Emacs as git mergetool"

Comment: @bsd emerge? Isnt that the package manager of gentoo?

Comment: In this case it's a command in `emacs` for comparing/merging two files, buffers, directories, etc. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Overview-of-Emerge.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35906/discussion-between-bsd-and-johnson-steward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That script from the Arch Wiki

This invocation of `emacs` that checks `(fboundp 'tool-bar-mode)` is testing whether your build of Emacs includes GUI support. It's possible to build Emacs without it to save a little bit of RAM and disk space¹, but it's uncommon. Unless you care about compatibility with Emacs builds that lack GUI support, forget about this bit.

You are thus left with

```
if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
  emacsclient -a "" -n -c "$@"
else
  emacsclient -a "" "$@"
fi
```

And even that level of complexity is necessary only if you want to have the call to `emacsclient` return immediately if it opens a new GUI window. (If it's running in the terminal, then it has to keep running until you finish using that terminal.) It's up to you to decide whether you like this behavior. If you don't then you can simply run

```
emacsclient -a "" "$@"
```

And if you start Emacs with your session anyway, e.g. as a systemd unit, then you don't need to tell `emacsclient` to start it. So we're left with

```
emacsclient "$@"
```

which I cannot simplify further.

### Your added requirement

> - stay in the terminal (…) if called with a file (…) or when graphical environment isn't present (…)
> - open a GUI window when called without a file (…) and return immediately

For that you need to test whether the script was called with arguments. I'm going to assume that if you pass any `emacsclient` option (e.g. `--eval`), that counts as an argument.

```
if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
  emacsclient -nw "$@"
elif [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
  emacsclient -c -n
else
  emacsclient -c
fi
```

¹  <sub>No GUI support means you don't need to have the requisite libraries installed. The `emacs` program can't start if the libraries it eneds aren't present, even if it isn't going to use the GUI features in that particular session.</sub>

Comment: Maybe I have not expressed myself clearly; question edited above; sorry :)

Comment: This way I never get a GUI window from emacsclient. Also I can't just get an empty emacs window (e.g. for `C-h t`) from merely an `emc`call.

Comment: @JohnsonSteward Well I sure couldn't have guessed those requirements, I'm not a mind reader. I've added an implementation of your requirement to my answer.

Comment: Uh.. You still ignored something in the question. If I do `emc blabla` in [`gmrun`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gmrun), I should get a GUI window.

Comment: @JohnsonSteward No, that's not what you asked for. You wrote “stay in the terminal (…) if called with a file” and that's what I implemented. If you want to change your requirements, ask a new question and **be sure to state your requirements clearly**.

Comment: `gmrun` is **not** a terminal.

Comment: @JohnsonSteward You mean that the script should handle the case when there was no terminal, and create a GUI frame in that case? That isn't in your specification. I'm getting tired of these ever-changing requirements, so I won't reply any further. Ask a new question if you care and **state your requirements clearly**. We are not mind readers.

Comment: uh.. sorry. Will be clearer next time..